# calculating various cuts of a circle

Tags: circles, pi

im trying to find some sort of formula to calculate lines within a circle.

[image: Circle devided by lines]

I need to find the length of the various lines within the circle from which I only know the diameter. Is there some sort of formula that uses the dropoff of a circles side from the center?

Thanks,
Martijn

Comment: What information is given about the lines in the circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $h$ is the distance of the line from the center and $r$ the radius of the circle, the length of the line is given by:
$$l=2\sqrt{r^2-h^2}$$

Comment: thanks but when I use r=100 and h=25 it gives me 193.64916731 where it should be somewhere near 86. Maybe I am typing that formula wrong? This isn't really my first language.

Comment: eg, what needs to be done with the 2 in your formula? does the rest have to be multiplied by 2? Did you forget the dot inbetween? Got this now that gives 193: 2 sqrt(100^2-25^2)

Comment: I put $2$ because the result of the $\sqrt{.}$ is the half of the line. It's an obvious consequence of the theorem of Pythagoras

Comment: Ah I get it now, thanks! this helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 equations to find the [**chord**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_%28geometry%29) length of a circle depending on the information given (ie, the things that you know about the circle)

---

1) **Given the radius and central angle**:
[image: circ1]

## $$l = 2\cdot r\cdot sin(\theta / 2)$$

where **r** is the radius of the circle

and **$\theta$** is the **angle** subtended at the center by the chord

*Use this formula if you know the radius and central angle of the circle.*

---

2) **Given the radius and distance to center**:
[image: circ2]

## $$l = 2\cdot\sqrt {r^{2} - h^{2}}$$

where **r**  is the radius of the circle

and **h**  is the perpendicular distance from the chord to the circle center

*This is a formula for the length of a chord if you know the radius and the perpendicular distance from the chord to the circle center. 

This formula is the result of a simple application of [Pythagoras' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).*

---